# xerox workcentre 3215 wifi setup on 16.04

Tags: xerox

I'm trying to set up a xerox workcentre 3215 machine on 16.04
managed to install the driver
can't get the wi-fi going, the computer simply doesn't find it, though the printer says it's connected.